# Bing Maps: Maximum Zoom level different on mobile than on desktop

Tags: bing-maps

I'm using the Bing Maps v8 control.

I can set the zoom level to 20 at a specific location (33.736167, -117.977764) and it is definitely zoomed in more than zoom level 19 on both mobile and desktop.  But if I set zoom level to 19, on the desktop I can zoom in to 20 but on mobile, I'm stuck at 19 (I can zoom out but not in).

I've tried setting maxZoomLevel when I create the map as well as by doing a setOptions with maxZoomLevel both before and after doing the setView on the map.  I've also tried setting the zoom level to 20 when I create the map, again to no avail.

Here's a snippet:

```
var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), { mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.aerial, zoom: 20});
map.setView({center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(33.736167, -117.977764), zoom: 20});
var pushpin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(map.getCenter(), null);
map.entities.push(pushpin);
```

You can see it working on desktop by pasting the snippet above here and hitting run:
https://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdk/mapcontrol/isdk/adddefaultpushpin#JS

Unfortunately, this playground won't let you customize the scripts when in mobile mode and the behavior doesn't reproduce when you switch chrome back and forth to mobile in the playground (I can get it to reproduce by switching to mobile in chrome developer tools in my own application and doing a refresh - but in the playground refresh in mobile).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the reason for this is that if you are using a mobile device with a high resolution screen (i.e. retina display), the map loads tiles from the next zoom level so as to double the pixel density of the rendered map.

That said, I'm not certain why you would be able to load a map at level 20 but not zoom into it in the same browser for the same location. However, if you are zooming into a different location, it is possible that tiles aren't available at zoom level 20 and thus the map doesn't let you zoom in. I recall Bing Maps having variable zoom levels since high detailed aerial imagery is only available in selected location.

Comment: Thanks.  The DPI explanation makes sense.  Either I was fooling myself, or a "but" was fixed since I can no longer reproduce the inconsistent behavior that I described.  Mobile/High DPI devices are just not zooming to the same level as desktop.